# Using satellite background images to draw features in PostGIS database?

Tags: qgis, postgis, openstreetmap, overlay, geomajas

What tool do I need to have satellite background images to draw features of a PostGIS database?

I looked about Geomajas but seems very complex for what I'm trying to do.

I have osm data imported in a postgis database, as a layer in QGIS. The second layer is what I am drawing, and the third layer that I ask here is how to have satellite imaginery on bottom of the two mentioned ones as a visual aid in drawing features.

Comment: Could you supply more details about your requirements, please?  For example are you trying to build a web or desktop application?  Do you have access to COTS or just Open Source software?

Comment: I apologize for the unclear question. I have osm data imported in a postgis database, as a layer in qgis. The second layer is what I am drawing, and the third layer that I ask here is how to have satellite imaginery on bottom of the two mentioned ones as a visual aid in drawing features.

Comment: @underdark - why was it closed so quickly? shouldn't the asker be given more time to respond?

Comment: re-opened on two users requests Martin0x777 please added your screenshot, thanks.

Comment: Thank you, but with the updated plugin, the rectangle does not appear anymore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how I would do it in a Desktop.

1. Get [QGIS Desktop](http://www.qgis.org/), an Open Source and popular GIS
   Desktop.
2. Install Openlayers Plugin(In Menu, `Plugins -> Fetch Python
   Plugins` would display the plugin)
3. Set Project CRS to `EPSG:3857`
4. Add Bing/Google Satellite Layer( `Plugins -> OpenLayers -> Add  Bing/Google`)
5. Add PostGis Layer(`Layer -> Add Postgis Layer`)

[image]

Comment: Technically correct answer, but i recommend checking Terms of Service agreement. I have faint recolelction that Google dosent allow it

Comment: I would use it only as a guide for the task of drawing some features.

Comment: I cannot attach a screenshot since this question is closed, but if I add a Google layer, I have this rectangle in the middle of the image that says "Map Data. copyright 2013 Google, Maplink, Mapcity Imaginery Terrametrics"... and this prevents me to see. With Bing I don't have this problem but it seems that there are different CRS. Thank you.

Comment: @Martin0x777 - I am not sure if the latest version of the plugin has this issue with google..in that case you could use bing..you might need to set the project coodinate system(CRS) to EPSG:4326

Comment: @vinayan - The project CRS should be set to EPSG:3857 when using openlayers plugin!

Comment: @AndreJoost - you are right! updated answer.

Comment: The updated openlayers-plugin works fine, thanks @vinayan :)